# How to write JS functions like operand(operator(operand))?

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to wrap my head around the logic for writing a function that looks something like `eight(times(five))` in JavaScript.

Example:

- `eight(times(five))` should return 40
- `three(plus(two))` should return 5

It was a Codewars problem. It provided empty functions for numbers 0-9 that looked like "eight( ){ }" as well as empty functions for operators that looked like "times( ){ }." The solution should be such that executing "eight(plus(three))" would return 11, etc.

Comment: **Comments are for clarification only.**  If the comment you're about to post is not about that, please refrain.  Read https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a function which returns either a value or a function call with the actual value. Then you nee a function for the operand which retuns a closure over the function for the value.

```js
function eight(fn) {
    return typeof fn === 'function' ? fn(8) : 8;
}

function times(fn) {
    return function (op) {
        return fn() * op;
    };
}

console.log(eight(times(eight)));
```

Comment: An issue with the above is it assumes that fn is a function; what would happen if one wrote eight(eight) ?

Comment: @ChrisCousins, actually you get an error `Function expected`. what would you like to get?

Comment: @ChrisCousins I mentioned in my comments above (that were actually related to the question) that the inner-most reference should also be a function call, which fixes that question. It's a pretty nutso DSL though considering how... many... numbers... there are ;)

Comment: @DaveNewton, what is *DSL*

Comment: @NinaScholz Domain Specific Language. Here, a limited mathematical language.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question got answered while i was writing this reply...but i will post it anyways.

```
function times(fn) {
    return function (op) {
        return fn() * op;
    };
}
function plus(fn) {
    return function (op) {
        return fn() + op;
    };
}
function minus(fn) {
    return function (op) {
        return fn() - op;
    };
};
createNumbers = () => {
    var num = 0;
    ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'].forEach((number) => {
        let val = num;
        window[number] = (fn) => {
            return fn ? fn(val) : val;
        };
        num++;
    });
};
createNumbers();
three(times(five)); // 15
eight(plus(two));// 10
etc
```

Comment: You can use a second parameter in your `forEach` callback instead of the `num` variable